# Heroku clock process already runs job when pushed to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, cron

I'm using the Heroku clock process to schedule jobs to run. This is my procfile.

```
web: node index.js
worker: node worker.js
clock: node clock.js
```

The following is my **clock.js**, which should run every 30th minute of the hour.

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const worker = require('./worker');

const job = new CronJob({
    cronTime: "30 */1 * * *",
    onTick: worker.start(),
    timeZone: "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh"
});

job.start();
```

My **worker.js** holds the code to be executed

```
exports.start = () => {
    // Code to be ran
};
```

> The issue when I push changes to Heroku, the code is executed straight away by my clock dyno, and at 30 past the hour nothing is happening.

[image]

Any idea if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the () at the end of worker.start. The parentheses make the function run immediately.

Comment: Aha that makes sense. Have you used the clock process before? It also seems like it didn't run when supposed to, but that might be because of the () as well. I'll check, thanks

Comment: I haven’t used cron before, but I think it’s the same concept as how setTimeout doesn’t work if you use ( ) after your function.

Answer (score 0):

This way you are starting the worker at the same Clock's Dyno. You should use RabbitMQ or something similar

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31294532)